# SectionsPagerAdapter not loading fragments correctly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I've got an android activity that displays 3 tabs using a SectionsPagerAdapter, one for received friend requests, one for sent friend requests and one for current friends.

When I open the activity, It defaults to tab 0, the received requests, but instead it loads the results from the queries (using parse.com) belonging to the Friends fragment. The Friends fragment usually doesn't show anything, but it runs the Sent Request queries in the background. When moving over to the Sent tab, it shows the right ones. However, when I go back to either of the other tabs, sometimes it will show me the Sent Requests list under one of the other tabs, or nothing at all, or one of the three chosen seemingly at random. Now, this is my first time working with tabbed fragments, so my problem probably lies there, however, I can't seem to find it.

Here's the code for the Friends activity that contains the tabs:

```
public class FriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch(position){
                case 0 : return ReceivedFragment.newInstance();
                case 1 : return ConnectionsFragment.newInstance();
                case 2 : return SentFragment.newInstance();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getText(R.string.received);
                case 1:
                    return getText(R.string.friends);
                case 2:
                    return getText(R.string.sent);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's my code for the friends list fragment:

```
public class ConnectionsFragment extends Fragment{

    public static ConnectionsFragment newInstance() {
        ConnectionsFragment fragment = new ConnectionsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public ConnectionsFragment()
    {

    }

    private SwipeMenuListView friendsListView;
    private ParseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connections, container, false);

        currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        friendsListView = (SwipeMenuListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friendsList);


        final ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
        final ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), searchResults);
        friendsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> senderQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("FriendRequest");
        senderQuery.whereEqualTo("sender_id", currentUser.getObjectId());
        senderQuery.whereEqualTo("status", "accepted");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> receiverQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("FriendRequest");
        receiverQuery.whereEqualTo("receiver_id", currentUser.getObjectId());
        receiverQuery.whereEqualTo("status", "accepted");

        List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
        queries.add(senderQuery);
        queries.add(receiverQuery);

        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> friendsQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

        friendsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("USERS", "Retrieved " + objects.size() + " Users");
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {

                        for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                            ParseUser foundUser = null;
                            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                            try {
                                if (dealsObject.get("receiver_id") == currentUser.getObjectId())
                                {
                                    foundUser = query.get(dealsObject.getString("receiver_id"));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foundUser = query.get(dealsObject.getString("sender_id"));
                                }
                                Log.i("NAME IN FRIENDSLIST", foundUser.getString("name"));
                            } catch (ParseException err) {
                                Log.e("ERROR", err.getMessage());
                            }

                            Log.i("NAME", foundUser.getString("name"));
                            final SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
                            sr1.setName(foundUser.getString("name"));
                            sr1.setSurname1(foundUser.getString("surname1"));
                            sr1.setSurname2(foundUser.getString("surname2"));
                            sr1.setUid(foundUser.getObjectId());
                            Log.d("UID", foundUser.getObjectId());

                            sr1.setPhone(foundUser.getString("username"));
                            sr1.setEmail(foundUser.getString("email"));

                            ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) foundUser.get("thumbnail");
                            try {
                                byte[] imageBytes = fileObject.getData();
                                sr1.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length));
                            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                            }

                            searchResults.add(sr1);
                        }
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else if (objects.size() == 0) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_search_results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("USERS", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = friendsListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults) o;
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        UserDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("uid", fullObject.getUid());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be unrelated to the issue but the way you are doing background loading could result in memory leaks because fragments try to destroy their views once theyre not visible anymore. You keep a reference to it in the probably long living ParseQuery instance which then prevents the adapter to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0 : return ReceivedFragment.newInstance();
            case 1 : return ConnectionsFragment.newInstance();
            case 2 : return SentFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
```

You are creating new instances of each fragment every time you swipe onto them. I would recommend using onResume() inside each fragment, and parse your information in there to avoid unnecessary activity creation.

```
public static class RecievedFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){}

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //Parse Info to this frag here
    }
}
```

and remove .newInstance() in getItem()

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0 : return ReceivedFragment;
            case 1 : return ConnectionsFragment;
            case 2 : return SentFragment;
        }
        return null;
```

I suspect your problem may be in how you parse the data to each fragment. Are you using one shared variable? Could you post your code showing how you handle in the parsing?

Comment: I'm using 3 fragments, one for each tab, along with one layout file for each fragment (which really only contains a ListView). I'll update the original question with one of the fragments (since the three fragments are very similar, only one part of the parse request changes)

Comment: If I remove the .newInstance(), then where do I call the fragment's constructor?

Comment: Actually, getItem is only called when the adapter needs to instantiate the given page fragment so you can just keep returning a new instance because It will only be called once per page. The PagerAdapter keeps all fragments in memory and handles the instances by itself.